# When keyboard appears it resets offset of inside views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikeyboard

By tapping on button I'm moving everything up and show UITextField in one of UIViews I'm moving:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.logo.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: -200)
}, completion: nil)
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.fill.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: -230)
}, completion: nil)
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.form.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: -240)
      self.form.alpha = 1.0
}, completion: nil)
```

But when I'm tapping on UITextfield (in form UIView) and keyboard appears it resetting offset of everything.

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using AutoLayout to place your items inside your view, which wants to fix your frame "misplacement". Add the `UITextField` with constraints and change the values in your constraints on your contents.

Also when you use `tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, your rows adapt to new heights automatically.

You shouldn't use `frame` for anything else than animations, where the outcome is already what AutoLayout expects.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Yes, I'm using AutoLayout.

Comment: I've had this problem as well and tried forcing frames to what I wanted, while the only thing I needed to do was to change one constraint.

Comment: @lenyapugachev Did that solve your problem? If so, accept this as the answer.